# Filtering rows of a DataTable with the return type of a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I would like to filter the rows of a DataTable and then perform a LINQ query on the resulting set of rows. The second query currently operates on a DataTable.AsEnumerable. The DataTable.Select method returns an array of DataRows. Is there anyway to perform a LINQ query on these, or convert a the array of DataRows to a DataTable, so I can chain the results of the filter into the linq query?

Comment: Is the LINQ query done immediately after the Select?  Can you combine them into a single LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

While you can convert the resultant array of DataRow objects to a new DataTable, your best bet is to simply perform your LINQ query against the DataRow array.  For example:

```
var queryReturn = from r in myDataRows 
                  where (int)r["IDColumn"] == 1
                  select r;
```